# How to make that bot can work in task manager?

Tags: python, windows, telegram-bot

I want to do that it program can work in task manager. I think that alternative webhook and want to try. If it is not good idea can you give some advice how to do that this program can work. I want to use this program not sometime, I wanna use it everyday

That just example. I can't send all code

```
import telebot
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Привет")

while True:
    try:
    bot.pooling(non-stop=True,interval=3,timeout=3)
    except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: what do you mean by task manager?

Comment: Have you considered posting to the [Russian SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: @ Axois  Task manager in windows